# Compare two list and output missing and extra element (Python)

Tags: python

I've 2 lists(sorted) of prefix and would like to compare it in Python so that I can output which element in the original list was missing and which was added.

Eg.

```
list1_original = ['1.1.1.1/24','2.2.2.2/24','3.3.3.3/24','4.4.4.4/24']
list2 = ['3.3.3.3/24','4.4.4.4/24','5.5.5.5/24','6.6.6.6/24']
```

I want to compare the 2 lists and output the add/remove element in list1_original. ie:

```
1.1.1.1/24, 2.2.2.2/24 = missing
5.5.5.5/24, 6.6.6.6/24 = added
```

Comment: How about using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)?  especially [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference) or [`set - set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference)

Comment: Or set symmetric difference.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If there is no duplicates in given lists you may use sets and their "-" operator:

```
list1 = ['1.1.1.1/24', '2.2.2.2/24', '3.3.3.3/24', '4.4.4.4/24']
list2 = ['3.3.3.3/24', '4.4.4.4/24', '5.5.5.5/24', '6.6.6.6/24']

set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)

missing = list(sorted(set1 - set2))
added = list(sorted(set2 - set1))

print('missing:', missing)
print('added:', added)
```

this prints

```
missing: ['1.1.1.1/24', '2.2.2.2/24']
added: ['5.5.5.5/24', '6.6.6.6/24']
```

Answer (score 6):

With [`sets`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/) you can compare lists:

```
missing = set(list1_original).difference(list2)
added = set(list2).difference(list1_original)
```

Keep in mind that the output is a set. To cast the output into a list you can use `list(missing)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result using a loop and some conditional statements.

```
list1 = ['1.1.1.1/24', '2.2.2.2/24', '3.3.3.3/24', '4.4.4.4/24']
list2 = ['3.3.3.3/24', '4.4.4.4/24', '5.5.5.5/24', '6.6.6.6/24']

for i in list1:
    if i in list2:
        print("added",i)
    else:
        print("missing",i)

missing 1.1.1.1/24
missing 2.2.2.2/24
added 3.3.3.3/24
added 4.4.4.4/24
```

Same thing can also be framed like so,

```
[print("added",i) if i in list2 else print("missing",i) for i in list1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work regardless duplicate values without sorted().

```
>>> def finder(arr1,arr2):
    for i in range(len(arr1)):
        if arr1[i] not in arr2:
            print("missing",arr1[i])
    for j in range(len(arr2)):
        if arr2[j] not in arr1:
            print("added",arr2[j])
```